# Character/String passed from java to stored procedure does not work

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, oracle11g, java-stored-procedures

Hi I have a stored procedure which accepts parameter "Q_RES" from java. Its value is either "Y" or "N" . In my stored procedure I have a condition

```
If Q_RES = 'Y' THEN
    sp_stat = 'TABLENAME.RES  IN (' || Q_RES || ')';
END IF
```

nut I get error has ORA-00904: "Y" invalid Identifier

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In PL/SQL assignment is Pascal style `:=', not`=`. Aside from that, I don't see any problem with the string concatenation shown here.

I suspect that `sp_stat` is being used later, in composing dynamic SQL. I would take a close look at the SQL being generated.  It's probably goign to look like this:

```
... TABLENAME.RES IN (Y) ...
```

And if that is interpreted as SQL text, Oracle is going to see that bareword `Y` as an identifier, such as a column name, and attempt to resolve that.  (If a table referenced in the query has a column named `Y`, the query wouldn't throw an error about an invalid identifier.

Just guessing here, but I suspect that we want Y to be a string literal. A string literal is enclosed in single quotes, like this:

```
... TABLENAME.RES IN ('Y') ...
```

To get a single quote inside a string literal, we can use two single quotes, e.g.

```
'I''m happy this is working'
```

---

Since we already know `Q_RES` is equal to `'Y'`, why not just do this:

```
sp_stat := 'TABLENAME.RES  IN (''Y'')';
                               ^^ ^^
```

or, if we want to reference `Q_RES`, enclose it in single quotes, like this:

```
sp_stat := 'TABLENAME.RES  IN (''' || Q_RES || ''')';
                               ^^               ^^
```